# Is it better to design a class with too many layers of encapsulation?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I am reading the book of *CPP-Concurrency-In-Action-2ed-2019*. In **chapter 9.1.2**, the author gives a simple example to show how to design a wrapper of type-erasure function:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class FunctionWrapper {
 public:
  FunctionWrapper() = default;

  FunctionWrapper(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;

  FunctionWrapper& operator=(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;

  FunctionWrapper(FunctionWrapper&& rhs) noexcept
      : impl_(std::move(rhs.impl_)) {}

  FunctionWrapper& operator=(FunctionWrapper&& rhs) noexcept {
    impl_ = std::move(rhs.impl_);
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename F>
  FunctionWrapper(F&& f) : impl_(new ImplType<F>(std::move(f))) {}

  void operator()() const { impl_->call(); }

 private:
  struct ImplBase {
    virtual void call() = 0;
    virtual ~ImplBase() = default;
  };

  template <typename F>
  struct ImplType : ImplBase {
    ImplType(F&& f) noexcept : f_(std::move(f)) {}
    void call() override { f_(); }

    F f_;
  };

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<ImplBase> impl_;
};
```

But what I wonder is that is it necessary(or in other words, a good pattern of design) to wrap a function. Because a funciton is encapsulated into `FunctionWrapper` with so many layers, such as `targer function->ImplType->ImplBase->std::unique_ptr<ImplBase>->FunctionWrapper`, then use it into `thread_pool` like

```
class ThreadPool {
  ...
 private:
  ConcurrentQueue<FunctionWrapper> q_;
};
```

To clarify it simply, why just use for instance `std::unique_ptr<F> impl_` in FunctionWrapper?

Comment: "is too many good?" - no. You write a wrapper when you do need a wrapper. When you do not need a wrapper then its not good design to use one

Comment: how else would you erase the type of the function? You can take a look at `std::function`, which is the standard library type for type erasure of callables. Its something you use when you do need type erasure. When you do not need type erasure, it has unecessary overhead

Comment: **type erasure** is the keyword here. Functions and callables are a complicated area of C++ language. Before dealing with complexity of type erasure over callables, you need to put some focus on researching **type erasure**. As one simpler example take a look at `std::any` and fancy how you can implement a simple form. `std::function` is too complicated to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

> why just use for instance `std::unique_ptr<F> impl_` in FunctionWrapper?

Because that would not be type erasure. If the member is of type `std::unique_ptr<F>` then `FunctionWrapper` for different `F` cannot be the same type. The class could be a template and the different types could be `FunctionWrapper<F1>` and `FunctionWrapper<F2>`.

However, the point of this class is to provide one type that is the same type independent of the underlying type of the function.

I am not familiar, with the book, hence I use the standard type erased `std::function` for the example:

```
  // some function
  void foo();

  std::function<void()> f;
  f = &foo;
  int x = 42
  f = [=](){ std::cout << x; };
```

`f` can store all kinds of callables. A `std::function<void()>` that stores a lambda and a `std::function<void()>` that stores a pointer to free function are of the same type: `std::function<void()>`. Only a callable that has different signature requires you to use a different type. For example a callable that returns `int` can be stored in a `std::function<int()>`.

The layer of indirection is not "too much". It is what is required for the type erasure. Sloppy speaking, the inheritance from `ImplBase` pushes the difference between the different types of callables, which is a difference at compile time, to virtual dispatch, which happens only at runtime.

When you are fine with some specific type of callable, for example `void(*)()`, pointer to free function, then you do not need type erasure. However, then you cannot store other types of callables in the function pointer. For example a lambda that captures a variable cannot be converted to pointer to free function.